# How to select the iframe elements using css?

Tags: css, iframe, css-selectors

I have few div's like as follows,

```
<div id="text-2">
<div class="textwidget">
<iframe id="widget-0" src=""></iframe>
<iframe id="widget-1" src=""></iframe>
</div>
</div>

<div id="text-3">
<div class="textwidget">
<iframe id="widget-2" src=""></iframe>
<iframe id="widget-3" src=""></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

In the above div's, i want to restrict(block/none) the iframes for particular page using css.

***For Example :***

(i). If i'm in home page,

I want to display the iframes like "widget-0" and "widget-2",and the remaining iframes "widget-1" and "widget-3" needs to be disabled.

(ii). If i'm in inner page,

I want to display the iframes like "widget-1" and "widget-3",and the remaining iframes "widget-0" and "widget-2" needs to be disabled.

How to do this using css. Can anyone help me in this small css tweaks.

***CSS Selector Example For Paragraph tag :***

```
div#test p:first-child {text-decoration: underline;}
div#test p:last-child {color: red;}
```

***Note :***

The iframe id's are dynamic, not static. Above one is simple example.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to reference them by their id's, like:

```
#widget-2 { display: none }
```

If you want this to be depended of the page you are currently in, you might want to add a class to the body element that indicates the page. With that, you can enable/disable the iframes the way you want:

```
<body class="home">
.home #widget-2 { display: none }
```

In the example above, now the second widget is only disabled on the homepage.

Comment: The widget id's are dynamic, i just given the example like that. If i want to hide the last element and display the first element means, what should i do using css selector for iframe.

Comment: Can't you use: iframe:first-child or iframe:nth-child ?

Comment: yeah, it's not applying that styles

Answer (score 1):

First add body class in home and inner ( like "home-page" "inner-page" )

```
 iframe { display: none }

 .home-page iframe#widget-0, .home iframe#widget-0 { display:block }

 .inner-page iframe#widget-1, .home iframe#widget-3 { display:block }
```